# R - extract number from string(special solution)

Tags: r, string, numbers, extract

i have a string like this  x <- "avd_1xx_2xx_3xx"
i need to extract the number from x(string) and put them in new variables 
num1 <- 1xx
num1 <- 2xx
num1 <- 3xx
however, i can't predict the number of digits for each number
for instance, this x would be "avd_1_2_3" or "avd_11_21_33" or likes

could you give me some solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr`.  To extract multiple matches we use `str_extract_all`, which returns a `list` of length 1 (as we have a single element in 'x').  To extract the `list` element, we can use `[[` i.e. `[[1]]`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\d+[a-z]*")[[1]]
#[1] "1xx" "2xx" "3xx"
```

A similar option using `base R` would be `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+[a-z]*", x))[[1]]
#[1] "1xx" "2xx" "3xx"
```

The pattern we match is one or more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by zero or more lower case letters (`[a-z]*`).

---

It is better to keep it as a `vector` rather than having multiple objects in the global environment.

Comment: Thank you,akrun. it does work. and could you tell me what [[1]] mean here?

Comment: @YamPakChing  I updated the post.  Thank you for your reply